# insert image in the article top left corner

Tags: html, css

find the image attachment,

image will showing the my article markup,

how to build the html wire frame, same like image attachment,

want to show image in the top left corner and article should start in the mid of the image,

and length of the article should continue and show the below of the article, same like what i

attached, which way is the best and suitable for my requirement, DIV/Table,

i guess with table not able to complete, DIV is the suitable one, but really i dont have where to start this,

is there any sample markup, please refer that link, [image]

Comment: Put the image and the text in a div. Then assign float: left; to the img.

Comment: Since you don't know yet how to create divs or assign styles, and I see you asked something else and I imageine this might go on, I would suggest you look for a good html-css tutorial to start with. It would be impossible to explain how to use positions if you don't know about these languages yet...

Comment: You need to understand some basic html and css first. Its not a very good practice to rely on tables for everything. Tables must be used only when they really make sense. And it advised to use divs in other scenarios. Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vC5rn/1/) this might be the kind of output you are expecting. I would suggest [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) for some basic understanding on html and css.

Comment: I wouldn't.  w3schools has enough outdated and downright wrong info that i wouldn't recommend it as a reference for anyone who doesn't already know enough to tell the good from the bad.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `style="float: left;"` or `align="left"` to your image. So your markup should look like this:

```
<img src="..." style="float: left;" />
<p>josh</p>
<p>It is a long es......</p>
```

Using `style="float: left;"` is considered better practice now because it uses CSS rather than DOM attributes. Make sure your image is above your text.

Comment: as well i want to put one cross image in the top right croner(X=>delete link)

Comment: In that case, right below the other `img`, put `<img src="..." style="float: right;" />`. It's the same idea. You can have one floating left and one right, just make sure they're above your text.

Answer (score -2):

You need to understand some basic html and css first. Its not a very good practice to rely on tables for everything. Tables must be used only when they really make sense. And it advised to use divs in other scenarios. Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vC5rn/1/), this might be the kind of output you are expecting.